# Angular data-binding not working with Jade

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express, pug

I wrote this test code just to check if Angular is working with Jade.

layout.jade

```
doctype html
html
  head
    title #{title}
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/style.css')
  body(ng-app='app')
    block content
    script(type="javascript" src="/vendor/bower/angular/angular.min.js")
    script(type="javascript" src="/public/app/module.js")
```

index.jade

```
extends layout
block content
  div(ng-controller="mainCtrl")
      h1 #{title}
        input(type="text" ng-model="something")
        | {{something}}
```

But {{something}} is always displayed as a string & not a placeholder.

This question has been asked a number of times, I have checked out the answers but couldn't fix it.

**SOLVED:**
*This should be useful for beginners*

Turns out I wasn't specifying the files correctly,

```
doctype html
html
  head
    title= title
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/style.css')
    script(type="text/javascript" src="/bower/angular/angular.min.js")
    script(type="text/javascript" src="/javascripts/app/module.js")
  body(ng-app="app")
    block content
```

As the directory of the static assets,

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

is already defined in the the express app.

Moreover, I had to add another middleware for 'vendor' in app.js (express) that is,

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'vendor')));

Comment: Is both in the same directory? Can you do extends layout.jade with the extension

Comment: fyi, this generator has sample files for jade + angular - https://github.com/DaftMonk/generator-angular-fullstack/tree/master/app/templates/client

Answer (score 0):

Try with something like this:

```
extends layout
block content
  div(ng-controller="mainCtrl")
      h1 #{title}
        input(type="text" ng-model="something")
          span(ng-bind="something")
```

Comment: Thank you, it works fine this way too. I wasn't specifying the files & middlewares correcty.